# HTMLのtextのonkeydownで半角数字のみ入力を指定したところテンキー入力が効かない。

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, .net

お世話になります。

Windows、VisualStudio2015のASP.NET(VisualBasic)、.NET Framework4.6、
ローカルIIS、ブラウザはGoogleChrome、IE、で開発しています。

１つのページにtext（ASP.NETではTextBox、名称はtxtTest）を置き、
半角数字のみ入力できるように、function(名称はnumOnly())を設定します。

HTMLのソースは以下の通りです。
functionは、`<head><script></script></head>`
に書いてあります。

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
<script>
<!--
// 半角数値のみを入力可能にする
function numOnly() {
  m = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  if("0123456789\b\r".indexOf(m, 0) < 0) return false;
  return true;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>・・・※A
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

また、プログラムにおいては、
ページをロードする際に、
次のコードを実行します。

---

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        txtTest.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return numOnly()")
End Sub
```

---

また、ブラウザで実行しますと、上記の※Aの部分のソースは、
以下のようになります。

---

```
<input name="txtTest" type="text" id="txtTest" onkeydown="return numOnly()" />
```

---

これにより、パソコンのキーボードの上の方に横に並んでいる数字キーで、
半角数字のみ入力はできるようになったのですが、
テンキーでの半角数字入力ができません。

これをできるようにしたいのですが、
何か適切な方法がございましたら、
ご教示いただけたら幸いです。

どうそよろしくお願いします。

（functionの参照元）
http://javascript.eweb-design.com/1205_no.html

`<SCRIPT>`という（大文字）はASP.NETでは適切でないようで、小文字に。
「language="JAVASCRIPT"」の個所もエラーになるため外してあります。

Answer (score 1):

参考にされているページでもテンキーでの入力ができません。
これは、`onkeydown` 時に得られる`keyCode` がキーボード上部のものとテンキーとで違うからです。

`onkeydown`の代わりに`onkeypress`を使ってみて下さい。

参考：[キーコード一覧](http://www.programming-magic.com/file/20080205232140/keycode_table.html)

Comment: 助かります。onkeypressの方でできました＾＾。

Answer (score 1):

半角数字のみ受け付けたいinputにしたい場合、keydownやkeypressのkeyCode見てはじくのはできるかもしれないですが、ブラウザや端末によって仕様が違いそうだし、コピペに対しては対応できないので現実的でない気がします。

入力された値 → 全角数字を半角数字に変換 → 半角数字以外を削除

みたいな値を変換するアプローチがいかがでしょうか？

```js
function digitsFilter (val){
  return val.replace(/[０-９]/g, function(s){ return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0); }).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="this.value = digitsFilter(this.value)">
```

setIntervalで値を変更するデモを追加

```js
function bindDigitsFilter(input){
  
  var intervalId = null;
  
  var filterValue = function(){
    if ( !/[^0-9]/.test(input.value) ) {
      return;
    }
    var len = input.value.length;
    var end = input.selectionEnd;
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[０-９]/g, function(s){ return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0); }).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    input.selectionEnd = end - (len - input.value.length);
  };
  
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(){
    if ( !intervalId ) {
      intervalId = setInterval(filterValue, 100);
    }
  });
  
  input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    filterValue();
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
  });

}

bindDigitsFilter(document.getElementById('input'));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: `value`を変更する場合、`selectionStart`を適切に設定しないとカレットが移動して使いづらくなると思います。

Comment: setIntervalとかで監視してvalue変更するようにするとカレットの位置も考慮する必要ありますね。

Comment: 助かります。試してみます＾＾。