# event.keyCodeによるテキスト入力の制限について

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, asp.net

お世話になります。

Windows、VisualStudio2015のASP.NET(VisualBasic)、.NET Framework4.6、
ローカルIIS、ブラウザはGoogleChrome、IE、で開発しています。

１つのページにtext（ASP.NETではTextBox、名称はtxtTest）を置き、
バックスペース、タブ、前後矢印、半角数字のみ入力できるように、
function(名称はnumOnly())を設定します。

以前質問させて頂きました内容に関連します。
[HTMLのtextのonkeydownで半角数字のみ入力を指定したところテンキー入力が効かない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31831/html%E3%81%AEtext%E3%81%AEonkeydown%E3%81%A7%E5%8D%8A%E8%A7%92%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%92%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%8C%E5%8A%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

文法に関する質問です。

WebページのソースにおけるHTMLを次のように書きます。

```
        function numOnly() {
            if ((48 <= event.keyCode) && (event.keyCode <= 57)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

このように書きますと、半角数字のみ入力可能になり、
バックスペース、タブ、前後矢印他、半角英文字の入力も利きません。
そこで、event.keyCodeの値について、バックスペース＝8、タブ＝9、前後矢印＝37と39を利用し、
次のように書き換えます。

```
    function numOnly() {
        if (event.keyCode = 8) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode = 9) {
            return true;
        }
         else if (event.keyCode = 37) {
            return true;
        }
         else if (event.keyCode = 39) {
            return true;
        }
         else if ((48 <= event.keyCode) && (event.keyCode <= 57)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

ところが、このように書きますと、半角英文字の入力が出来てしまいます。
この原因が分かりません。

書き方に不備があるようでしたら、
ご教示頂けましたら幸いです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

条件の`event.keyCode = 8`が代入(`=`)になっているのですべて等値比較(`==`)に書き換えてください。

Comment: 助かります。「==」にするのですね。